# Undirected Edges in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to make undirected edges in my graphs, but I can't figure it out. Here is a sample code:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[->,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};


  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge [above] node {} (2)
         edge [bend right] node [right] {} (2)
         edge [bend left] node [right] {} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Answer (score 5):

Slightly simplified code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
        \usetikzlibrary{positioning}

    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[
        shorten >=1pt, auto, thick,
        node distance=3cm,
    main node/.style={circle,draw,fill=blue!20,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}
                            ]
      \node[main node] (1) {1};
      \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};

      \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
        (1) edge [bend right] node {a} (2)
            edge node {b} (2)
            edge [bend  left] node {c} (2);
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Some comment: if you don't like arrowed paths, then don't define them. The first option `->` at the top of the picture is selecting an arrow for all paths where applicable. Hence removing that option removes the default arrowing behavior.

For nodes you can select `auto`. This means that you not need to declare their position anymore and they will be placed relative to the path. And why do you define nodes on edges if you then do not use them? I put letters in them to show their position on the edges.

I also omit `center` environment since I do not know of it purposes. For `\documentclass` I select `standalone`. It gives me just a picture.

[image]

Comment: Either both or none of the two ends should be short of the target.

Comment: I agree, but in OP MWE is (to me not logical) showed just one. To shorten bots sides of edges OP need to add `shorten <=1pt` in TikZ picture option.

Answer (score 0):

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[-,>=stealth',shorten >=1pt,auto,node distance=3cm,
  thick,main node/.style={circle,fill=blue!20,draw,font=\sffamily\Large\bfseries}]

  \node[main node] (1) {1};
  \node[main node] (2) [right of=1] {2};


  \path[every node/.style={font=\sffamily\small}]
    (1) edge [above] node {} (2)
         edge [bend right] node [right] {} (2)
         edge [bend left] node [right] {} (2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Removing the arrow fixes it.

Comment: Some notes: (1) You don't need to specify `node [right] {}` in your path, it already exists. (2) Replace the `center` environment with a `figure` one, then add `\centering` right after the opening tag. (3) Your `every node` definition is not doing anything since there are no (visible) nodes in your path. Also, I'd rather place it inside of a tikzset. You can override it by applying another style locally, like with `main node`. (4) Use `right =of 1` (the equal sign right before the `of`), see [Difference between “right of=” and “right=of” in PGF/TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/9386/4778)

Comment: @Alenanno Well, `figure` isn't *always* the correct thing.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I didn't say "always"?

Comment: @Alenanno No, but you don't know the context for this diagram, and still you recommended to replace `center` with `figure` and `\centering`, which could then be interpreted as *'never use the `center` environment for diagrams/figures in the text, always use `figure`'*. It could well be that `figure` is the way to go, but we cannot say from the information that is available.

Comment: @TorbjørnT.  *"which could then be interpreted as..."*. please don't apply your interpretation to what others have said. That's not what my comment says, so you're actually replying to something I never said.

Comment: By the way, since this is a figure, in what case you'd say the figure environment is not advisable for this code?